CATIA V5 - Automated Detailed View Generation - VBA
I am working on a project at work aimed at automating the CAD process for shaft design. We have already seen significant success with the 3D design aspect. However, we are encountering some challenges with the drafting portion. The drawings consist of four views:

Side view where you can see shaft lengthwise

Section view where you can see shaft lengthwise

Detailed view of the left side of the shaft

Detailed view of the right side of the shaft


The length of the shafts varies, and if the shaft is too long, a broken view is applied to the first two views. This makes positioning the detailed view window challenging. What I have been trying to do is select the side view and list all the generated items found in this view along with their corresponding locations. By using the points farthest to the left and right on the X-axis, I can position these detailed view windows. Unfortunately, my code is unable to access the locations of these generated items. By 'generated items,' I mean all the lines and points that make up the drawing view.
Many thanks :)
Can someone please take a look at my code and give me advice on how I could make this work?

CODE --> VBA
Sub CATMain()

    Dim drawingDocument1 As drawingDocument
    Set drawingDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

    Dim selection1 As selection
    Set selection1 = drawingDocument1.selection

    Dim Sheet As DrawingSheet
    Set Sheet = drawingDocument1.Sheets.ActiveSheet

    Dim View As DrawingView
    Set View = Sheet.Views.ActiveView

    Dim Selec_2 As selection
    Set Selec_2 = drawingDocument1.selection
    Selec_2.Add View

    ' Perform the search for generated items
    selection1.Search "CATDrwSearch.CATEarlyGenItem,sel"
    
    ' List all found items with their locations in the Immediate Window
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To selection1.Count
        ' Get the current element
        Dim element As Object
        Set element = selection1.Item(i).Value
        
        ' Print item type and index to Immediate Window
        Debug.Print "Item " & i & ": " & TypeName(element)
        
        ' Try to get the element's location if available
        On Error Resume Next
        
        Select Case TypeName(element)
            Case "Line2D"
                Debug.Print "Start Point X: " & element.StartPoint.x & ", Start Point Y: " & element.StartPoint.Y
                Debug.Print "End Point X: " & element.EndPoint.x & ", End Point Y: " & element.EndPoint.Y
            Case "Circle2D"
                Debug.Print "Center X: " & element.Center.x & ", Center Y: " & element.Center.Y
                Debug.Print "Radius: " & element.Radius
            Case "Text2D"
                Debug.Print "Anchor Point X: " & element.AnchorPoint.x & ", Anchor Point Y: " & element.AnchorPoint.Y
                Debug.Print "Text: " & element.Text
            Case Else
                ' Attempt to access generic X, Y if available
                If HasProperty(element, "X") And HasProperty(element, "Y") Then
                    Debug.Print "Location X: " & element.x & ", Location Y: " & element.Y
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Location data not available for this type."
                End If
        End Select
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
    Next i

End Sub

' Helper function to check if an element has a property
Function HasProperty(obj As Object, propName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasProperty = Not IsNull(CallByName(obj, propName, VbGet))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function ```


The projected geometry (from 3d) is not accessible via the api. You may use the values size of the view (dimension of bounding frame) to calculate the position of your detailed view.
